# Why I don't need to declare encoding when using python interpreter?

Tags: python, character-encoding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I understand that this line of code is necessary when non-ascii characters are involved in python script file.

When I was learning python, I was told that the two ways of running python code (line by line in interpreter vs run a script file) would yield the same result. And they actually do, in most cases. But when non-ascii characters involved in scripts, it turns out that I have to declare encoding first.

Moreover, I have tried exec() function, trying to execute a string containing python codes.

```
>>> exec ("b='你'")
```

it works.

But if I save "b = '你'" to a script and run it, I will get syntax error.

I am curious about why I don't need to declare encoding when running python codes line by line in interpreter.

Is there any difference in executing procedures of these two way?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose an interactive session of Python use the [`system encoding`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) (see also [Python Unicode strings and the Python interactive interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421145/python-unicode-strings-and-the-python-interactive-interpreter)).

When it read a source file, it need to know how to interpret the data it's parsing
It's logical the script is not necessary written in the same encoding than the terminal executing it; and even more when the script is ran without an environment specifying the encoding.

Also, it is interesting to read **Joel Spolsky**  [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which might explain why Python choose to require the developers to be explicit about the encoding (which I would have preferred that they set a default to UTF8, but their way is coherent with the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

Comment: No, the encoding `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns is not the same as is used when parsing in interactive mode. For example I get `"ascii"`, but are still able to `print "ä"`.

Comment: Oops, you are right, i mixed system and default encoding while writing the answer; thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Because standard in already has an encoding (`sys.stdin.encoding`).

The encoding of `stdin` can come from various sources depending on platform. On Apple and Windows its predefined (`"utf-8"` for Apple and `"mbcs"` for windows), otherwise it's determined from the current locale as given by `LC_ALL` or `LANG` (if `LC_ALL` is missing) environment variable.

If you're running under linux you can for example do run `LC_ALL=en_GB.ascii python` and your example should fail.

Comment: does Python not use `LC_ALL`?  I'm not suggesting that `LANG` is wrong, I'm just surprised it still uses it.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, thanks for pointing that out. `LC_ALL` have precedence over `LANG`.

Comment: I had a play, and I think it might differ on OS X and Linux.

Comment: @cdarke If running on OS X you get `"utf-8"` anyway. Correct?